# Default author not working in blogdown

Tags: r, blogdown

I've followed the instructions in Yihui Xie's book and setup a blog using 
RStudio + RMarkdown + Hugo > Github > Netlify.

Every time I create a new post with the Addins > New Post dropdown in RStudio the author is blank even though I have created a .Rprofile file located in my home directory with the single line:

```
options(blogdown.author = "First Last")
```

What silly thing am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you restart R?

Comment: Hi Yihui. Restarted many times. I've never been able to get the defaults to work.

Comment: What does `getOption('blogdown.author')` return in the R console?

Comment: > getOption('blogdown.author')
NULL

Comment: You probably need to read the documentation again: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/global-options.html (in particular, the second paragraph)

Comment: Alas, I think I'm following these instructions. A simple .Rprofile file with a single line options(blogdown.author = "First Last"). I've tried placing the file in my home directory (~) as well as where the .Rproj file resides. Restarted R each time. All to no avail.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. It is hard to diagnose the problem here. The worst case is you just run `options(blogdown.author = "First Last")` once every time you open RStudio.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help, regardless.

Comment: Problem solved! I needed at extra blank line at the end of the .Rprofile file. I knew it was silly.

Comment: I remember I heard of this at least once before. It is indeed odd and very hard to discover. Thanks for posting back! You can answer and accept your own question below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved! I needed at extra blank line at the end of the .Rprofile file.